# Need to use a pointer to an object without knowing the object data type in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, inheritance

I am trying to store a pointer to an object so that I can call a function in that object at a later time.  I want to do this without having to know the object type (I know the base object but not the derived object)

I am using void * in my example but i understand that this is not the solution.

```
struct rec {
    void *obj;
} myvar;

class A {
    void add() {
        myvar.obj = this;
    }
    virtual void foo();
}
class B : public A {
    void foo() {}
}
class C : public A {
    void foo() {}
}

C c;
c.add();

myvar.obj->foo();
```

I'm just trying to figure out the best way to implement this.  I think a class template is appropriate but could use some help in the correct syntax for the definition.

Comment: Why store a `void*` instead of a `A*`?

Comment: If you know the object is `A` or derived from `A`, make the pointer `A*`.

Comment: There is not much you can do with a `void*` pointer.  `static_cast<A*>(myvar.obj)->foo();` is one thing you could do.

Comment: In addition to the above comments: consider using a reference to A instead of a pointer to A, if that's possible in your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of polymorphism is to be able to call virtual methods on a pointer/reference to a base class without having to know the actual derived type that is being pointed/referred to. Using a `void*` pointer circumvents the compiler's ability to use that system.

So, simply store a pointer to your base class (`A*`) instead of a `void*`.  Use a [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) if you need to.

For example:

```
class A; // <-- forward declaration to base class

struct rec {
    A *obj; // <-- use a pointer to base class, not void
} myvar;

class A {
public:
    void add() {
        myvar.obj = this;
    }
    virtual void foo();
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() { ... }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void foo() { ... }
};

C c;
c.add();

myvar.obj->foo(); // <-- OK now!
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2rPan9)